# How can we delete all numbers and . (dot) in all lines within a file using vim?

Tags: vim

How can we delete all numbers and . (dot) in all lines within a file using vim ?
For example, we have a file has the following.

```
afsdfsd 0.98096764
afsdfd 0.98196765
0.98096764
afsadfsd 0.98096764
adfsd 0.98096764
aadfsd 0.98096425
0.98096425
afsadfsd 0.98096761
```

`
Wonder how we can some feature in vim to delete all numbers and the dot within the number (in my file, the dot only exits within the numbers)

```
afsdfsd  
afsdfd  
 
afsadfsd  
adfsd  
aadfsd  
  
afsadfsd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with regex, but I think it's simpler to use `tr` to just delete the character ranges you want:

```
:%!tr -d '.[0-9]'
```

The colon starts "command mode."  The `%` means "entire buffer"; the `!` means "filter the specified range (entire buffer) through the following shell command (i.e. feed it on the command's stdin, and replace it in Vim with the stdout from that command)."

Answer (score 4):

```
:%s/[0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)\?//g
```

This Basic Regular Expression (BRE) search & replace operation removes one-more-more digits optionally followed by a dot and one-or-more digits.

`vim` also understands PCRE's `\d` as a synonym for `[[:digits:]]`, so you could shorten that a bit with:

```
 :%s/\d\+\(\.\d\+\)\?//g
```

BTW, see `:help perl-patterns` in `vim`.

This would not only be shorter, but would also work in locales where `0-9` aren't digits, or aren't the only digits.

You could make it even shorter (and, IMO, much more readable) by using `\v` in the regex to enable vim's [very magic](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic) regex mode:

```
%s/\v\d+(\.\d+)?//g
```

See also `:help magic` in `vim`.

BTW, a simpler regex (like `:%s/[0-9.]\+//g`) would also remove periods used as punctuation (e.g. at the end of sentences, or ellipses `...`).

Answer (score 2):

You can chain two substitute commands together with a `|` symbol. Therefore,
you can first delete all digits (`\d`) and then all periods (`\.`):

`:%s/\d//g | %s/\.//g`

You can also use the pipe as an 'OR' operator in a single substitution command:

`:%s/\d\|\.//g`